# Thoughts about $\alpha-$Holder continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis

I was thinking about the relationship of the $\alpha-$Holder continuous functions and their derivatives.

The question is: If $f\in C^{k,\alpha}$, whats the better conditions to $f^{(k+1)}$?

For example, taking $\alpha=k=1$. If $f\in C^{1,1}$ and $f''$ exists, whats can I say about $f''$? $f''$ is integrable?

Just a thinking.

Comment: Why do you think that $f^{(k+1)}$ exists?

Comment: I forgot of put this hypothesis. Thanks @gerw.

Comment: If $f\in C^{1,1}$ then $f'$ is Lipschitz, so it is differentiable a.e. and $f''$ is bounded.